# Add a refinable inside my Search Result Web-part to filter based on the library name

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search-results, managed-property, search-results-webpart

I have 5 document libraries inside my SharePoint online site collection, and i create a search result web part to filer and search documents from the 5 document libraries (the 5 document libraries uses the same content type). but i am not sure if i can add a refinable inside my search result web part, to filter the documents based on their library name or title, i can see there is a managed property for ListID, but not sure if i can user or create a managed property for the List Title/Name?

Answer (score 1):

There is no refiner that is pointing to document library name. As a workaround you need to create a new hidden column in the document library, give it default library name. Add a managed property tagging this column and then after the crawl add it to the refinement panel. refer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/234e7ce6-58c8-49cc-8d4a-1553e834c7d7/add-document-library-name-to-refinement-panel-on-sharepoint-2010-search?forum=sharepointsearchprevious).